# Packaging scala class on databricks (error: not found: value dbutils)

Tags: scala, apache-spark, databricks

Trying to make a package with a class

```
package x.y.Log


import scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer
import org.apache.spark.sql.{DataFrame}
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{lit, explode, collect_list, struct}
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{StructField, StructType}
import java.util.Calendar
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import spark.implicits._

class Log{
...
}
```

Everything runs fine on same notebook, but once I try to create package that I could use in other notebooks I get errors:

```
<notebook>:11: error: not found: object spark
import spark.implicits._
       ^
<notebook>:21: error: not found: value dbutils
  val notebookPath = dbutils.notebook.getContext().notebookPath.get
                     ^
<notebook>:22: error: not found: value dbutils
  val userName = dbutils.notebook.getContext.tags("user")
                 ^
<notebook>:23: error: not found: value dbutils
  val userId = dbutils.notebook.getContext.tags("userId")
               ^
<notebook>:41: error: not found: value spark
    var rawMeta =  spark.read.format("json").option("multiLine", true).load("/FileStore/tables/xxx.json")
                   ^
<notebook>:42: error: value $ is not a member of StringContext
    .filter($"Name".isin(readSources))
```

Anyone knows how to package this class with these libs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are running Spark 2.x, the  statement `import spark.implicits._` only works when you have SparkSession object in the scope. The object Implicits is defined inside the SparkSession object. This object extends the SQLImplicits from previous verisons of spark [Link to SparkSession code on Github](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/c26379b446e90b3104ebe36f288be483f613a652/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/SparkSession.scala). You can check the link to verify

```
package x.y.Log


import scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer
import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{lit, explode, collect_list, struct}
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{StructField, StructType}
import java.util.Calendar
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

class Log{

  val spark: SparkSession = SparkSession.builder.enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate()

  import spark.implicits._

  ...[rest of the code below]
}
```

Comment: It worked, thanks.
Also imported 
import com.databricks.dbutils_v1.DBUtilsHolder.dbutils
for dbutils problem